# My footer isn't sitting at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm having trouble with the footer of my website. I want it to stick to the bottom of the page (after its content)
Can someone help me?

EDIT: I can see the footer with my second screen (the bigest one) but in my laptop screen I can only see 1/4th of the footer.

codepen link!
https://codepen.io/jimdiew/pen/zYrPQdP

html

```
<body>
<div class="site-container">
    <nav class="header-main">
     <label class="logo"><span style="color: #0199a7">ESTUDIO</span>CUATRO</label>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>  
        <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>      
     </ul>       
    </nav>
<main class="site-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/1.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #1</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/4.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #5</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
            
         </div> 
         <div class="column">
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/2.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #2</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/3.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #6</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="column">
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/3.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #3</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/2.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #7</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="column">
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/4.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #4</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">  
                        <div class="content-overlay"></div> 
                            <img class="content-image" src="images/1.jpg">
                                <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h1 class="content-title">Proyecto #8</h1>
                                    <p class="content-text">Ver más fotos</p>
                                
                                </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div> 

    </div>
    
</main> 
<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ecuatro.arquitectos/" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/ecuatro.arquitectos/" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>  
</div>
```

css

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.site-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.site-content{
    flex:1;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   }

.header-main{
    background: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

label.logo{
    color: #98979b;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-main ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-main ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.header-main ul li a {
    color: #aaabad;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    border: 3px; 
}

.header-main a.active, a:hover {
    background: #6dc4c6;
    transition: .3s;
}

.header-main ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

 /*SLIDER*/

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

slider {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #98979b;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

slider > * {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #98979b;
    animation: slide 12s infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

slide:nth-child(1){
    left: 0%;
    animation-delay: -1s;
    background-image: url(images/image-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(2){
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    background-image: url(images/image-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(3){
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    background-image: url(images/image-3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;   
}

slide:nth-child(4){
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 8s;
    background-image: url(images/image-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(5){
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 11s;
    background-image: url(images/image-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

@keyframes slide{
    0% { left: 100%; width: 100%; }
    5% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: 0%; }
    30% { left: -100%; width: 100%; }
    30.0001% { left: -100%; width:0%; }
    100% { left:100%; width:0%; }
}

.site-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background: #6dc4c6;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-social-icons{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer-social-icons ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: right;    
}

.footer-social-icons ul li {
    display: inline-block;    
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li a{
    color: #98979b;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li a i {
    line-height: 30px;

}

.footer-social-icons ul li  a:hover i{
    color: #98979b;
}

.site-content {
    background-color:  #98979b;
    position: relative;

}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
}

.column {
    flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
    background: rgba(109, 196, 198, 1);
    position: absolute;
    height: 99%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.content-image{
    width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
  
.content:hover .content-details{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
  
.content-details h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .content-details p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  
  .fadeIn-bottom{
    top: 80%;
  }

/* PARA MOBILE */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
      flex: 50%;
      max-width: 50%;
    }
    .container{
        width: 33.33333%;
      }
  }

@media (max-width: 640px) {
    label.logo {
       font-size: 40px;  
       text-align: center;
       width: 100%;
       padding:0;
       display: block;
    }
    .container{
        width: 100%;
      }

   ul{
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 30vh;
       background: #6dc4c6;
       top: 80px;
       left: 0;
       text-align: center;
   }
   nav {
       color: white;
   }
   nav ul li {
       display: block;
   }
   nav ul li a {
       font-size: 20px;
       color: white;
   }
   a:hover, a.active{
       background: none;
       color: #0199a7;
   }
   slider{ 
    margin-top: 240px;
    }
    .column {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here as text, preferably a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're NOT trying to have the footer stick to the bottom of the window as you scroll, but have it show up at the very bottom of the page after you've scrolled past all the content.

### Option 1

If all of your pages are long, then the simpler way to do this is just to let the footer sit naturally in the flow of the page: remove `position: absolute` from `.site-footer` and remove `height: 100%` from `html, body`. However, if there is a page (or browser) where the window is taller than the content of the page, the footer won't stick to the bottom of the page with this solution.

### Option 2

If you want it to stick to the bottom of the window when content is short and sit at the bottom of the page when content is long, it would be better to make the following changes:

First, remove `height: 100%` and `padding: 0` from `html` and `html, body`. (Note that it would be better to consolidate your `html` and `body` styles because it'll be annoying to troubleshoot anything else since your downstream styles will just overwrite your styles higher in the file since they're at the same level of specificity.)

Then, add the following to `body`:

```
min-height: 100vh;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 60px;
```

Since `.site-footer` is a child element of `body`, `body` is the one that needs to have `position: relative` which can then allow us to absolutely position the footer relative to it. Also, we use `100vh` (100% viewport height) since just `100%` can be weird because it could use the height of the content inside or the height of the parent container depending, so it's just easier to deal with vh. And adding additional padding to the bottom is so that there's space for the footer since it's outside the flow of the page. And finally, I would suggest setting the background color of the `body` to be #98979b as well so you don't have a weird white gap if the content is too short.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see the relevant code running to be more specific, but it will most likely need something like this:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the bottom: 0; from the .site-footer class

```
.site-footer {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
background: #6dc4c6;
padding: 15px 0px;
**bottom: 0;**
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: I tried deleting the position and the bottom line but nothing changes :/